Help identify this terrific Asian (?) squash
I was trying to buy a winter melon at a local Asian market. Not super familiar with winter melon, I thought I found one, dark green, about 20" long, but it seemed unusual in that it had a bulgy bottom, not just a smooth cylinder -- but I thought that might just be age.
When I got it home and cut it open, it was yellow inside (winter melon is, AFAIK, white inside). And when we cooked it in soup, it was wonderful! Quick-cooking, soft and sweet, like candied pumpkin, really terrific.
I did save some of the seeds, but I'd like to know what it is. I don't have photos of the whole thing, because we didn't love it until we'd eaten it.



Note that for a true winter melon this would be too thin. The diameter would be more around 25cm/ 10 inches. Also, in all the Asian super markets I've been to, winter melon was only ever sold in pieces, I've never seen a whole one.

That's very helpful. We grew one or two squashes from seeds labeled "winter melon." They started out fuzzy and got smooth later, but they never got terribly big, maybe 3-4" diameter. I suspect it was something else, maybe fuzzy melon? Oh these curcurbits!

I suspect that what you have here is a Marrow or at least a hybrid of marrow with something else.  Marrow themselves are the mature form of courgette/zucchini, so they are a long fruit, up to about 60 cm/2 feet long. They are usually about 10-15 cm/5-6 in across. The flesh tends to be whiteish and the skin is relatively soft compared to that of a pumpkin. They are quick cooking and have sweet, firm flesh that softens rapidly during cooking. They do indeed make a delicious soup and is commonly used by many Asian families that I know in my country for making soups.
All the Cucurbitaceae (cucumber, pumpkin, squash, gourd etc. family) hybridize very easily, so you tend to get features of one carrying over to another, making exact identification almost impossible. It might be a hybrid of marrow with a type of pumpkin to give the more yellow flesh and the bulging stem.

Thanks! We grew "marrows" last summer, often accidentally leaving a zucchini too long when we didn't find it. This is not very like, though it certainly might be a hybrid. It's sweet in a way zucchini never is, with yellow flesh and a stem like a butternut.
